# Can't get Variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to send a POST request to my HTTP Server on my ESP8266. 4 Variables should be transmitted: onhour, offhour, onminute, offminute. I want catch up the variables from my timepicker-component which I imported from "ng-bootstrap"

I have already tried several methods to do this but even after 3 days of messing around it wont work. I'm really new to Angular and this are my first steps with it. Also I have already bought a course on udemy but as already mentioned these are my first steps...

In the html file I can show up the variables but I'm not able to use it in typescript, they even update.

Following lifecycle should be realized:
INPUT the on and offtime -> CLICK save -> CALL method -> SEND data via post to backend -> PROCESSING in backend -> ACTING

```
export class TimepickerComponent implements OnInit {
ontime = {hour: '', minute: ''};
offtime = {hour: '', minute: ''};

onhour  = this.ontime.hour;
onminute = this.ontime.minute;
offhour = this.offtime.hour;
offminute = this.offtime.minute;
postData = {};
url = '192.168.4.1/settimes';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
this.postData = {
onhour: this.onhour,
onminute: this.onminute,
offhour: this.offhour,
offminute: this.offminute
};
}
```

I uploaded the full code for better view on CodePile:
HTML - https://www.codepile.net/pile/72MLn1pl
TS - https://www.codepile.net/pile/XRWPD67w

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqe97g

Comment: I'm done, should be reproduced now.

Comment: where is your stackblitz link. fork above repo and reproduce

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1z7qtv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `postData` object is created in your constuctor and does not hold references to your variables in the view. You should construct your `postData` object in your `postTimes` function.

See this example:

```
var obj1 = { name : '' };

var val = obj1.name;

var data = { name : val };

val = 'bar';

console.log(data) // { name : ''}

var postData = { name : val };

console.log(postData); // { name: 'bar'}
```

Comment: THANK YOUR VERY MUCH! This was the missing logic that i need. Now lets get on the Http request ^^